# CSS - background image repeat x from a starting point

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have an h2 that I am trying to fit with a 2px background image. I want the image to begin after the words in the h2, and then repeat-x for the remainder of the space in the h2. Since words lengths vary, I can't simply put a static image in the html.

I can get the background image in just fine and repeating along the x-axis. But the image goes behind the text, which I don't want.

Is there a way to either 1. start the image repeating from right after the text, or 2. accomplish this task in a better way?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78qqW/) for what I have so far.

... and the accompanying code:

```
h2{

color:#253b74;
font-size:16px;
background-image:url('http://s8.postimg.org/ke8tx8jhd/hr_03.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-position:100% 50%;

}
```

and html:

```
<h2>PRODUCT IMAGE</h2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
<h2><span>PRODUCT IMAGE</span></h2>

h2 {
    color:#253b74;
    font-size:16px;
    background-image:url('http://s8.postimg.org/ke8tx8jhd/hr_03.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:100% 50%;
}
h2 span {
    background:white;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eQBgs/

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<h2><span style="background: white;">PRODUCT IMAGE</span></h2>
```